# No pasting allowed in Command Prompt after Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-10-v1607

Windows has long allowed you to paste text into the command prompt by right-clicking to bring up the context menu and selecting "Paste". Before the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I could paste passwords during password prompts, which is very useful when doing command line builds of certain applications which require passwords to be entered as part of the process.

After the anniversary update, the context menu is not available during a password prompt, so there doesn't appear to be any way to paste a password into the command prompt. Is there a way to bring back the context menu, or a special keyboard shortcut (ctrl-v doesn't work in the command prompt) in order to paste a password?

Comment: I am able to paste into the command prompt during a password prompt by using either Ctrl+V or (right-)clicking the icon in the top-left corner, and then going to Edit -> Paste. What are the commands you're having trouble with?

Comment: I can even paste by simply right-clicking in the command prompt (also during a password prompt). I would find it odd if none of these three options work for you.

Comment: Ctrl+V DOES work in the command prompt in Windows 10, it is a newly added feature.  As @FastEthernet is saying, it works fine here too. Exactly which "password prompt" are you trying to paste into?  How can we reproduce to test?

Comment: Hmm... that's very strange. Give me a few minutes while I find the line in the batch file that's asking for a password. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, it's not directly within any of the batch files. This is happening when making an iOS build of an Adobe AIR app from FlashDevelop, using the PackageApp.bat script as a starting point. When building for ad-hoc or app-store, the user is prompted for the publishing certificate password. I can't find the password prompt in the batch files, so I guess it's coming from AIR's command-line build utility. The prompt shows "password: " and characters entered during this prompt do not appear on the screen (similar to password entry on Linux terminals)

Comment: It looks like Ctrl-V works after all. Is this a new feature in the Anniversary update? I could have sworn that even in Windows 10, it would enter special characters instead of pasting.

Comment: Pasting text into W10 cmd prompt has been there since the beginning...http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/09/windows-10-command-prompt-finally-gets-dragged-into-the-21st-century/

Comment: @Moab If those were "experimental" features, as shown in the screenshot in that Ars Technica article, perhaps they were not enabled by default. However, they are no longer "experimental" features. I could have sworn that as recently as two weeks ago I was getting ^V if I tried to paste into the command-prompt out of habit. Well, the important thing is it supports ctrl-v pasting now.

Comment: It has worked since RTM, I use it all the time.

Comment: @Moab But was it enabled by default, or did you have to edit the settings?

Comment: Enabled by default.

Comment: Weird, maybe I'm just crazy